# What's the difference between the Partition GUID Code and Partition unique GUID?

Tags: gpt

I'm just reading up on GUID partition tables, and messing around with `gdisk`, I see these two titles.

What is the difference between them?

I am referring to the following (emphasis mine) shown when running `gdisk`:

> GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.7
>
> Type device filename, or press  to exit: /dev/sda
>   Partition table scan:
>   MBR: protective
>   BSD: not present
>   APM: not present
>   GPT: present
>
> Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
>
> Command (? for help): i
>   Partition number (1-7): 4
>
> **Partition GUID code: EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7 (Microsoft basic data)**
>
> **Partition unique GUID: 85E66D2F-3709-4060-938E-FFE836433CC9**
>   First sector: 2844672 (at 1.4 GiB)
>   Last sector: 651208703 (at 310.5 GiB) Partition size: 648364032
>   sectors (309.2 GiB) Attribute flags: 0000000000000000 Partition name:
>   'Basic data partition'
>
> Command (? for help):

Comment: Could you include the relevant sections of whatever it is you are reading? As well as the actual source of the information.

Comment: I've included more information, and made bold the parts in question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The partition unique GUID is generated at the time that the partition is created. It uniquely identifies the partition at least inside the disk and probably among all the disks you own (because it's unbelievably rare for GUIDs to collide).

A partition GUID code (by which I believe you mean a partition type GUID), on the other hand, is a known, fixed GUID. It identifies the type of data inside that partition. For example, if you had a partition that contained an ordinary GNU/Linux filesystem, you would assign it a partition type GUID of `0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4` (defined as "GNU/Linux filesystem data"). If that partition was used as your `/home`, you would give it a GUID of `933AC7E1-2EB4-4F13-B844-0E14E2AEF915` (defined as "GNU/Linux /home"). If that partition was encrypted with, say, LUKS, you would give it a GUID of `CA7D7CCB-63ED-4C53-861C-1742536059CC` (defined as "LUKS partition"). [And so on and so forth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_type_GUIDs).

tl;dr: the partition unique GUID identifies *that exact partition*. The partition GUID code identifies the *type* of data inside that particular partition.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a LUKS type code in gdisk?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai I wrote this answer ~1.5 years ago, but IIRC, I used `fdisk`. my guess is that `gdisk` just didn't deem it necessary to include the LUKS type code for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

The "Partition GUID Code" is also called the "Partition type GUID".  Every partition type has a GUID instead of the 1 byte code that MBR used ([list of known partition types on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_type_GUIDs)).

The partition unique GUID is the (as the name implies) a GUID identifying that partition.  A new GUID is created every time you create a partition.