# How to create a Windows-compatible partition with a GPT partition table?

Tags: partition, fdisk, ntfs, gpt

I need to create a partition that is compatible with Windows 10 (preferably using NTFS) on a disk using a GPT partition table. Which partition type should I pick?

On non-GPT (DOS I think), using `fdisk`, I can pick the partition with ID 7, but on GPT I am uncertain which I should use from 10–13 and 16 (or something else entirely).

Note: I am using fdisk v2.36.

Comment: I recommend avoiding `fdisk` on this one. Please try `gdisk`, it will pay out.

Answer (score 6):

You have the `fdisk` code in another answer.  But note that you don't have to use `fdisk`.  There are other partitioning tools, and one in particular might be useful here.

On Rod Smith's `gdisk` the *Microsoft Basic Data* partition type is shorthand code 0700 in the tool.  `gdisk` shorthand codes are in hexadecimal, and are 16-bit integers rather than the underlying (128-bit) GUIDs used in the actual EFI partition table (which the tool maps the shorthands to, internally).

`gdisk` uses the convention of the old 8-bit MBR-style partition type multiplied by 0x0100 for its shorthand codes and is possibly easier to get to grips with in this respect with if one is coming from the MBR-style partition codes and DOS+Windows tools, as you apparently are.

One can list the shorthands interactively within `gdisk` with its `l` command, or by running the `sgdisk --list-types` command.  `sgdisk` is the non-interactive tool.

## Further reading

- [What's the difference between the Partition GUID Code and Partition unique GUID?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/121176/5132)
- Rod Smith (2018-06-07). *[GPT fdisk Tutorial](https://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/)*. rodsbooks.com.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2006). "[How partition types (do not) imply filesystem types](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/determining-filesystem-type.html#PartitionTypes)".  *How to determine the filesystem type of a volume*.  Frequently Given Answers.